# Joomla/Virtuemart: Sub-Menu items not showing on vertical menu

Tags: css, joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart, submenu

I have **mod_mainmenu** module on the left side of my page. I have a menu that I've created out of various URL's to different categories in Virtuemart. I did not use the Virtuemart catergories module because I didn't want ALL categories to appear, only certain ones.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be happening?

**==MORE INFO: 01/24/12==**

I want the sub-menus to slide or something when I scrollover or click on them, but they aren't.
Start Level is at 0, End Level is at 10, and Always show sub-menu items is on No. When I change 'Always show sub-menu items' to 'Yes', it will show the sub-menu items, but I don't want them to always show.

Another strange thing: I tried using the RokNavMenu module since I know that it has a slide feature, and that one doesn't do it either.

The 'ARI Ext Menu' module does, but it won't show the names of the sub-menus, just bullet points.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 settings you need to look at in your module config - Start Level, End Level, and Always show sub-menu Items. Keep in mind that numbering starts at 0, so start level should be 0, End Level should be some number greater than the number of submenu levels you have or plan to have, and Always show sub-menu items should be set to yes.

Comment: I want the sub-menus to slide or something when I scrollover or click on them, but they aren't.
Start Level is at 0, End Level is at 10, and Always show sub-menu items is on No. When I change 'Always show sub-menu items' to 'Yes', it will show the sub-menu items, but I don't want them to always show.

Another strange thing: I tried using the RokNavMenu module since I know that it has a slide feature, and that one doesn't do it either.

The 'ARI Ext Menu' module does, but it won't show the names of the sub-menus, just bullet points.

Comment: The standard Joomla menu doesn't have any special features, those would have to be added. Other than that, there are dozens of different menu modules that do all kinds of stuff. It looks like you are having a javascript conflict with both the RokNavMenu and the ARI Ext menu. You'll need to find out why they are not working on your site, some other extension is most likely loading up some JS that is causing an issue.